# Cannot serialize null integer fields in a wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I am getting the following error in my WCF service when trying to serialize data from my service to the client. I know **why** the error is happening, but I don't know **how** to resolve it.

> ExceptionType: CommunicationException - Communication error in either the service or client application
>   Error: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetRyderVehiclesResult. The InnerException message was 'ValueType 'System.Int32' cannot be null.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

There is a null integer property that I need serialized. It's nullable on my service and it's processed just fine, but when I look at the generated proxy on the client, it's **not** nullable.

**How can I get the property on the client when configuring my wcf service reference to be nullable?**

Here is my property on the server side.

```
private int? vehicleOdometer;

[DataMember(Name = "VehicleOdometer")]
public int? VehicleOdometer
{
   get { return vehicleOdometer; }
   set { vehicleOdometer = value; }
}
```

Here is the generated property on my client. Notice how it's **not** nullable.

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public int VehicleOdometer {
    get { return this.VehicleOdometerField; }
    set { 
           if ((this.VehicleOdometerField.Equals(value) != true)) {
              this.VehicleOdometerField = value;
              this.RaisePropertyChanged("VehicleOdometer");
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: Could this be because the property was originally int and has been changed to nullable int? You could try rebuilding your WCF service and regenerating the proxy to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Update the `Service Reference`

Comment: Have you tried setting `IsRequired=false` on the data member?  I.e., [DataMember(IsRequired=false)]`?

Comment: DeanOC/Silvermind, I rebuilt the proxy / service reference with the new nullable integer, but still doesn't show up in the proxy.

Comment: Tim, I placed the IsRequired=false in there, rebuilt my service, reconfigured my client to update the service reference and is still not nullable....

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **trick**.

```
private int vehicleOdometer;
private int? vehicleOdometerExposed;

public int VehicleOdometer
    {
        get { if (vehicleOdometerExposed != null) return (int)vehicleOdometerExposed; else return -1; }
        set { vehicleOdometer = value; vehicleOdometerExposed = value; }
    }
[DataMember(Name = "VehicleOdometer")]
public int? VehicleOdometerExposed
    {
        get { return vehicleOdometerExposed; }
        set { vehicleOdometerExposed = value; }
    }
```

1. To the outer world you will expose VehicleOdometerExposed with a name VehicleOdometer.
2. Do service side coding with the property VehicleOdometer.
3. Have a look at the two properties, VehicleOdometer is not the datamember but It is getting data from VehicleOdometerExposed which is a datamember.
4. If VehicleOdometerExposed is left untouched by the client your VehicleOdometer property at service side will give you -1 (you can change it to -9999 or any other number of your choice).
5. A -1 will tell you that client did not send anything.

That is the only way I believe nullables can be implemented with a DataContractSerializer.

Hope it will help.

Comment: What I needed to do was to completely delete my Service Reference, clean my solution, and then re-add my service reference back again... This time the nullable fields were there simply using my original technique.

Comment: @sagesky36 If you solved your problem this way, please, consider posting this as an answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

> What I needed to do was to completely delete my Service Reference, clean my solution, and then re-add my service reference back again... This time the nullable fields were there simply using my original technique. – sagesky36 Mar 28 '14

This comment solved the problem for me.  Removed Reference, Cleaned my solution, Rebuilt the service (got an error before I did this), and re-added the reference and all worked.